# What does <int:question_id> do?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am learning Django and there's an expression in code "int:question_id" which I'm not getting.

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [

    path('', views.index, name='index'),

    path('<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),

    path('<int:question_id>/results/', views.results, name='results'),

    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

Answer (score 3):

That's djangos way of describing a URL pattern. It means:

> Exepect an integer (`int`) to be present in the URL at this point & bind it to the `question_id` argument of the `views.results` method.

So if you have path "/12/results" then the corresponding method `views.results` will be called like this:

```
results(request, question_id=12)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a Path converter.

Basically it matches from zero to any positive number, the path that follows it.

In your example:

```
path('<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
```

The "question_id" path must be a number.

By the way a quickly explanation of path converters is found in the [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/#path-converters)

Answer (score 0):

I works likes this:
If the link, as an example, `my-domain.com/12` is clicked, then 12 will be passed to the "detail" url and consequently to `view.detail` . So your view should be as below:

```
def detail(request, question_id):
    ...
```